Example of a forcing notion with finite-predecessor condition that does not add reals
This question seems very basic but I cannot seem to find any literature on it.
Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a forcing notion. If $p$ is a condition of $\mathbb{P}$, define the predecessor set of $p$ to be $$\{q \in \mathbb{P} : p \leq_{\mathbb{P}} q \}.$$ Now assume every condition of $\mathbb{P}$ has a finite predecessor set. Is it possible for $\mathbb{P}$ to add no reals? If so, what is an example of such $\mathbb{P}$?

There is a zoo of forcing notions adding interesting objects (Suslin trees, clubs, $\square$ sequences,...) with "finite conditions", which would satisfy your property. They are often proper, but I'm not sure whether they add reals or not.

The answer is yes, because every forcing notion is equivalent to a forcing notion with finite predecessors.
Theorem. Every forcing notion is forcing equivalent to a forcing notion with finite conditions, a family of finite sets ordered by (reverse) inclusion. All such forcing notions have the finite-predecessor condition mentioned in the question.
Proof. Consider any forcing notion $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\P$. Let $\P^*$ be the forcing notion consisting of the finite pointed subsets of $\P$, that is, finite sets $a\subset\P$ such that $a$ has a least element. We order $\P^*$ by $a\leq b$ if and only if $b\subseteq a$. Since a finite set has only finitely many subsets, this will ensure that $\P^*$ has the finite-predecessor condition.
It is easy to see that $\P^*$ projects to $\P$ by mapping every pointed set to its point. So forcing with $\P^*$ adds a generic for $\P$.
Conversely, I claim that forcing with $\P$ adds a generic for $\P^*$. Assume that $G\subset\P$ is $V$-generic, and let $G^*$ consist of the finite pointed subsets of $G$. This is a filter in $\P^*$, since $G$ is a filter in $\P$. This is $V$-generic for $\P^*$, since if $D^*\subset\P^*$ is dense, then let $D$ consist of the least points of any pointed set in $D^*$ — this will be dense in $\P$. So there is some $q\in D$ which is least in some $b\in D^*$ such that $q\in G$. So $b\subset G$ and thus $b\in G^*$ and so $G^*$ meets $D^*$. So $G^*$ is $V$-generic for $\P^*$.
Since $G$ and $G^*$ are easily constructed from each other, we have $V[G]=V[G^*]$, and so these forcing notions are forcing equivalent. $\Box$
Meanwhile, as Monroe mentions in the comments, a drawback of this observation is that the forcing notion $\P^*$ is not generally separative, since pointed sets in $\P$ can use the same least point but be inclusion incomparable, so they will be incomparable in the $\P^*$ order but compatible with exactly the same conditions, violating separativity. I would view it as a natural version of the question to inquire about separative posets with the finite-predecessor property.

Very nice answer, Joel! Let me add that a variant of this question, Is there a dense subposet with the upwards-finite property?, is more subtle. The answer is no for some posets and yes for others, and it seems a subtle question where exactly the dividing line lies. For example, it's independent of ZFC whether every ccc poset has this property.

$\mathbb P^*$ is non-separative.  What about for separative $\mathbb P$?

@MonroeEskew Good question.

This general equivalence cannot be true for separative $\mathbb P$ because if $\mathbb P$ is separative, nontrivial, and countably distributive, then it is forced that the generic $G$ contains some strictly descending $\omega$-chain.  If $p$ decides such a chain, then $p$ must be a lower bound of the chain.

Good. That doesn't quite answer for the OP's case of merely not adding reals, though.
